# Where to download Spark SQL's spark-sql_2.10-1.3.1.jar from?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Please bear with my dumm question.
When I download Spark package (spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop1.tgz)I don't see the Spark SQL JAR (spark-sql_2.10-1.3.1.jar) under lib folder. Where can I get that? Isn't included by default on the spark package?

Please help.

Comment: It is better if you can build whatever version from source, then you will get all the jars you need even though it takes a little time initially.  Prepackaged spark versions does not come with all the modules you may need.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the jar from:http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.10/1.3.1